# Load external scripts with requirejs without access to config

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs, datatables

I'm trying to load the datatables javascript library in a plugin that I'm writing. The issue is that I get a conflict when I load the external resource, because datatables is conflicting with something when I call require.

```
<!-- DataTables -->
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.9.4/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
...
<script type="text/javascript">
    require(['forum/admin/footer']);  <-- crashes here, line 281
</script>
```

Here's the error message:

```
Uncaught Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module: function (h){var j=function(e){function o(a,b){var c=j.defaults.columns,d=a.aoColumns.length,c=h.extend({},j.models.oColumn,c,{sSortingClass:a.oClasses.sSortable,sSortingClassJUI:a.oClasses.sSor...<omitted>...ch require.js:8
B require.js:8
M require.js:15
d require.js:26
requirejs require.js:31
(anonymous function) (index):281
```

Since this is a plugin, I have restrictions I'm trying to work around, such as not being able to call require.config() at the beginning to specify paths for resources. I saw someone use the `define` call like

`define('resource', ['http://cdn.ajax.blah']);`

[in this blog](http://blog.cbsides.com/RequireJS-What-Not-To-Do.html)
but it doesn't look like it can be used that way since every other example has a function as a 2nd parameter.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The method used in the question does not work because DataTables is AMD-aware. If it detects that there's an AMD-style loader (which RequireJS is), then it defines itself as a module. However, it is **invalid** for AMD modules to be loaded with `<script>`, hence the error message.

The module in `forum/admin/footer` should be defined so as to require DataTables:

```
define([..., 
        '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.9.4/jquery.dataTables.min.js'], 
        function (...) {
});
```

(There's no need for a parameter corresponding to the DataTables module since it is a jQuery plugin.)

A few additional notes regarding the wider issue of integrating this plugin in a site that has already configured RequireJS:

1. `require.config` could be called multiple times to add configuration. However this may be deemed unacceptable if no coordination is expected between the plugin and the main code.
2. RequireJS has a notion of [context](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#multiversion). The documentation talks about it for loading multiple versions but maybe it can be fruitfully adapted to allow a plugin-specific configuration.

Comment: I could hit the inside of the function parameter in a require call, with all the scripts loaded (jquery.js, jquery-ui.js, code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js, jquery.min.js, jquery.datatables.js) but now I'm still getting the problem where dataTable() isn't a callable function from a jquery object.

Comment: Is jQuery loaded more than once? The kind of setup you mention is one in which the risk of this happening is high. For instance, if the main code loads jQuery and makes it accessible as the `"jquery"` module and your plugin *also* loads jQuery but loads it from a CDN then the DataTables plugin will install itself on the jQuery module loaded by the main code, not the one loaded by the plugin.

Comment: I'll dig in to see why those are all getting loaded. I actually played around with it more and got it to work, but would you be able to tell me why this works: http://jsfiddle.net/zMqZ3/7/ and this one doesn't: http://jsfiddle.net/zMqZ3/5/

Comment: The one that works works pretty much due to chance. RequireJS is loaded, then jQuery is loaded and it detects that RequireJS is already there so it calls `define`, etc. The second one does not work because the folks at DataTables decided that version 1.10-dev would call `define("datatables", ...)`. My answer was written according to the last released version, which does not do this. The upshot is that from 1.10 onwards you have to request DataTables by the name `"datatables"` and set a path to find the actual file. Previous versions did not need this.

Answer (score 11):

Have you just tried a simple:

```
require(['//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.9.4/jquery.dataTables.min.js']);
```

It works for local files without a doubt.

Comment: this actually works, just not the way I need it to. it would load the library fine, but since it was asynchronous, the $(document).ready() function would fire (where I was calling the datatables plugin) before the script was loaded.